# a4j:commandButton not reached the oncomplete

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I am using `Richfaces 3.3.3Final` sometimes the `a4j:commandButton` action are not completed, 
no more page reRendered.

**sample codes :**

```
<a4j:commandButton image="#{Icon.gotoIcon}"
                   id="gotoLinkId"                                                       
                   action="#{Home.gotoLinkAction}"
                   oncomplete="linkExpand('#{Home.id}');"
                   reRender="modalPanel,navigationMenu"/>
```

after the button click action the `panelMenuGroup` will be automatically expanded, but sometimes page hanged. And also tried to clear the cookies, no effect.

```
<rich:panelMenuGroup id="groupId"
                     label="About"
                     action="#{Home.homeLinkAction}"
                     expandMode="ajax"
                     reRender="navigationMenuId">

    <!-- Development -->

    <rich:panelMenuItem>
        <a4j:commandLink id="developmentMenuId"
                         value="Development"
                         action="#{Home.developmentMenuAction}"
                         reRender="mainOutputPanelId">
            <f:param id="ParamId" name="nameId" value="Development"/>
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </rich:panelMenuItem>
</rich:panelMenuGroup>
```

**Script :**

```
function linkExpand(id)
   {
       var elementId = "iconNavigationId:"+id;
       document.getElementById(elementId).click();
   }
```

When i try manually expand the panelMenuGroup no more actions should be completed. I got the below exception,

**Exception :**

```
debug[15:47:22,701]: Script evaluation succeeded
debug[15:47:22,701]: Evaluate script replaced area in document: 
error[15:47:22,717]: . Error message: Invalid argument.
debug[15:47:22,717]: call selectSingleNode for id= org.ajax4jsf.oncomplete
debug[15:47:22,732]: Call request oncomplete function after processing updates
debug[15:47:22,748]: call selectSingleNode for id= _ajax:data
```

Comment: Can you try putting an `alert` in `linkExpand` JS function (just to know if the code is being executed)?

Comment: @Apurv it works all the PC except a particular machine(s). It occurs not only in IE both FireFox and Google Chrome wont work.

Comment: Its more difficult to find, some times it works perfectly, but some times it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

`oncomplete`'s el-expressoins are evaluated early. Use jsFunction instead.